# How to loop over an array in CoffeeScript?

Tags: ruby, coffeescript

I want to loop over the array `lists_indexes` to update several lists of values in my HTML page.

Currently, I update a single such list through:

```
$('#List_1').html("<%= escape_javascript(options_for_select(@values, disabled: @disabled)) %>")
```

How do I loop over `lists_indexes` to update `List_2`, `...`, `List_n`?

Comment: An array, containing the lists indexes.

Comment: list_indexes = [1, 2, 3, 4..., n]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need is this, you dont need to loop over in CoffeScript, you can loop via ruby

```
<% list_indexes.each do |i| %>
$("#List_<%= i %>").html("<%= escape_javascript(options_for_select(@values, disabled: @disabled)) %>")
<% end %>
```

Comment: Yes, but that's not the answer I expect, because I'm not in a context where I can loop in ruby. I'm not going through a ruby controller, there. The Coffeescript is triggered by a remote script triggered by a view. So there is no way I can loop in ruby. I need to loop in the Coffeescript .js.erb

Comment: @cedric You're already in a context where you're using Ruby--what do you think `<%= ... %>` and `escape_javascript` are? It's an erb file.

Comment: OK, I just realised I could embed Coffeescript within Ruby code, as well as Ruby code within Coffeescript, INSIDE a .js.erb file. I had no idea it was possible to do this, I'm sorry. What is obvious to one is not to another, I'm afraid...Well, so now I learnt something BIG. Thanks !